# How to replace parts of code automatically on check in to TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'd like to write a hook or check-in policy to TFS, that would for example find all occurences of:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   MySuperLoger.LogException("some msg", params, e);
   throw;
}
```

in the code that is being checked in, and replace those with:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   MySuperLoger.LogExceptionWithoutStackTrace("some msg", params, e);
   throw;
}
```

Disregarding the point of doing that, I really need to have possibility to edit code that is part of pending changes that are being checked in.
I tried googling this, then reading [Team Services service hooks events docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/events) but it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Daniel. You should not change the files based at check-in/check-out, this will cause too many issues along the way. It's also why the Check-in policies don't have an elegant way to handle these kinds of issues. [Buck Hodges from the Visual Studio/TFS team once wrote a detailed blog post on why this is a bad idea.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2007/07/07/keyword-expansion-in-tfs/)

### Resharper

It's better to invest in a bit of validation code. The easiest way to do this, if you have Resharper, is to [create a Search template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html) and then save that as a inspection. With Resharper you can even do a solution wide search and replace to very quickly fix all occurrences in the code.
[image]

Choosing Replace will search the whole solution for any occurrence and will allow you to fix this in one go. Notice that this will only hit occurrences in a Catch block.
[image]

You can save this pattern and then, from the Pattern Catalog, turn it into an Inspection of the desired error level:
[image]

Using Resharper CLI you can add these inspection to a commandline based build, which allows you to integrate it with Visual Studio Team Services Build quite easily.

### Roslyn

If you do not own Resharper, it's going to be a little more work, implementing a Roslyn Analyzer is a great way to handle these issues in the IDE and in the Build process, both on the client as well as on a Continuous Integration build, but will require a bit of a learning curve.

### Solve the core problem

Another alternative is to simply rename the old method in your SuperLogger or to mark it `[Obsolete("Use LogExceptionWithoutStackTrace instead.")]`. You can tell it to throw an error as well or simply redirecting the `LogException` method to the method that doesn't include the stack trace by "overloading" it.

```
// Will result in a compiler warning when this method is used
[Obsolete("Use MysuperLogger.LogExceptionWithoutStacktrace instead.")]
public static void LogException(string msg, Exception e)

// Add , true to have the compiler throw an error when this method is used
[Obsolete("Use MysuperLogger.LogExceptionWithoutStacktrace instead.", true)]
public static void LogException(string msg, Exception e)
```

Or mark it obsolete and redirect at the same time:

```
[Obsolete("Use MysuperLogger.LogExceptionWithoutStacktrace instead.")]
public static void LogException(string msg, Exception e)
{
    LogExceptionWithoutStacktrace(msg, e);
}
```

With Obsolete marked Resharper will automatically offer a replacement if you format the error message cleverly:

[image]

Comment: @DanielMann raising the bar ;)

Comment: I'd love to hear how you've chosen to continue.

Comment: Well your answer got me thinking, and I have chosen a different approach for solving my problem. As I should not change the code as I wanned to, I decided to change the framework I was working on, so it can behave well with the code instrumentations already in place at my company. Before I somehow didn't see how I could possibly to that :)

As for the example I've given, my idea was not that LogException should be obsolete, it's just I'd like to log call stack only once - when it's not being rethrown again, so that it will be placed once, on the bottom of logs.

Comment: Great to hear you've found a better solution :). Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where writing a custom code analysis rule (a Roslyn analyzer, FxCop, SonarQube, whatever) and enforcing it via a gated check-in or pull request is the correct course of action. Your commit/build process should never change code.